# My mother in law is trying to take a car that is under my name. What can I do?

Tags: car

So I went half on a down payment with my child's grandmother. I’ve been making the payments. I told her we can meet in a public place and she went crazy saying that she co-signed for the car, which she didn't.

She is threatening to call the lot so they can pick up the car. I told her I was still gonna pay the half that I owed her, and she said she didn’t want the money.
I want the car knowing it’s under my name, but she is trying to take me to court and using a fake account to ruin my relationship. What can I do?

Comment: She may not realise this, but the only rights that being a co-signer gives her is to pay the car loan back if you don’t pay.

Answer (score 10):

You need to check who is on the **title** to determine who has rights to do anything with the car. Co-signing or making payments doesn't entitle you to anything.

If your name is the only one on the title, then I wouldn't worry about being sued in court. You would pretty easily win. if she tries to take the car without ownership you can report it stolen to the police. Don't take law into your own hands.